# copying a div or any borders, for an html email

Tags: html-email

This may seem like a very easy question for a some people, but I've been asked to make an html email signature for someone at my office.

Doing a little googling it seems that for gmail, all you need to do is design the signature that you want to use, then copy and paste the whole thing into their signature box, then you should be good to go.

The problem I'm running into is I can only copy the text, I can't find a way to copy the borders of my div (I tried using a table for this too, but ran into the same issue.

I tried to find a way to work around this, by seeing if there was somewhere I could just input pure html into their signature box, but it renders as text, not as html.

After searching around for a while I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue yet, any help would be appreciated!(will add html below)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #box {
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                height: 130px;
                width: 285px;
            }
            #name{
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;

            }

            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=box>
            <p id=name> ———— John Doe ———— </p>

        </div>

        <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to consider in an HTML email signature.  You need to develop and design it just as you would a regular HTML email. This means ALL styling should be inlined - especially Gmail as it ignores all Style tags.  You also need to take into account the CSS that is available for each client (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

You will also want to test this signature across each client as the email client you are using may in fact change the code you put in prior to sending and each email client's pre-processor may delete or further edit your code upon delivery.

A great article about creating an email signature: http://www.sitepoint.com/the-art-of-designing-and-marking-up-email-signatures/

This is your code inlined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; height: 130px; width: 285px;">
            <p style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"> &#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212; John Doe &#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212; </p>

        </div>

        <table>
            <tr> 
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll be sure to check out those links, Thank you!